# Java class loading from Jar file

Tags: java, jvm

I have a huge jar file with several classes, but my object graph in my application require only two classes A and B (along with other default classes required by JVM). If that's the case, will Java load the whole Jar file into memory? I mean should I create another Jar file with only classes A and B? I have read the class loading mechanism in Java, and I guess Java will only load the required classes in addition to the default classes, but I am not sure. Thanks for your time.

Comment: it will load the classes that your application uses at runtime. Regarding creating another jar the answer is no, you do not need to make more than one jar for your application.

Answer (score 1):

> will Java load the whole Jar file into memory?

If you put that `.jar` file on the class-path - yes, JVM will load entire `.jar` into memory allocated for the process;

> I mean should I create another Jar file with only classes A and B?

Seems like it does not (yet) use [JPMS of Project Jigsaw](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/), and most likely, it is better to package those two classes separately, yes;

> I have read the class loading mechanism in Java, and I guess Java will only load the required classes in addition to the default classes, but I am not sure.

Despite the fact, that `.jar` will be loaded into memory, Java will *not* load classes if they are NOT used, in your application, at all.

They are loaded **when they are required by the application**.

At the moment the class is used/required, the Java `ClassLoader` is called by the Java Runtime Environment and this(these) ClassLoader(s) load classes into memory dynamically.

Class is required/used, means anything from this:

- Class is instantiated (its object is created);
- Static member (method or field) of that class is accessed/referenced;
- Class is accessed by reflection;
- Class has been run from command line / shell.

Comment: Thanks. That means, the Jar file will be loaded into memory entirely, but only few items will be parsed into a class based on what is in the application. Is my understanding correct? If so, reducing the size of Jar file will help in reducing the memory footprint, even though most of the classes there won't be used. Am I right?